# Tuples/ArrayList of pairs

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, hashtable

I'm essentially trying to create a list of pairs which is proving frustratingly difficult

Note before anyone mentions Hashtables that there will be duplicates which I don't care about.

For example, if I do

```
$b = @{"dog" = "cat"}
```

I get

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
dog                            cat
```

which is good. However, I'm then unable to add the likes of

```
$b += @{"dog" = "horse"}
```

> Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'dog'  Key being added: 'dog'

I'm just trying to create a table of data **which I can add to** using something like `.Add()` or `+=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Persistent13's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54373986/45375) offers an effective and efficient solution - albeit a slightly obscure one.

Creating an *array* of hashtables is the simplest solution, though it's important to note that "extending" an array means implicitly *recreating* it, given that arrays are fixed-size data structures, which can become a performance problem with many iterations:

```
# Using array-construction operator ",", create a single-element array
# containing a hashtable
$b = , @{ dog = "cat"} 

# "Extend" array $b by appending another hashtable.
# Technically, a new array must be allocated that contains the original array's
# elements plus the newly added one.
$b += @{ dog = "horse"}
```

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5643) discusses a potential future enhancement to make PowerShell natively support an efficiently extensible list-like data type or for it to even *default* to such a data type. (As of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.2.0, PowerShell defaults to fixed-size arrays, of type `[object[]]`).

Answer (score 2):

I believe a list of hashtables should accomplish what you are after.

```
$ht = @{foo='bar'}
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]]::new()
$list.Add($ht)
$list.Add($ht)
$list.Add($ht)
$list
```

Comment: Thanks but i get the below error when trying to define $list


`Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Generic.List1[[System.Collections.Hashtable, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]] doesn't contain a method named 'new'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $results = [System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]]::new()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`

Comment: You're on an older version of PowerShell then. You'll have to use `$list = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]'`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list of tuples I'd recommend actually building a list of [tuples](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/09/02/using-a-tuple-in-powershell/):

```
$list = @()

$tuple1 = New-Object 'Tuple[String,String]' 'dog', 'cat'
$tuple2 = New-Object 'Tuple[String,String]' 'dog', 'horse'

$list += $tuple1
$list

# Output:
#
# Item1 Item2 Length
# ----- ----- ------
# dog   cat        2

$list += $tuple2
$list

# Output:
#
# Item1 Item2 Length
# ----- ----- ------
# dog   cat        2
# dog   horse      2
```

Note that in this example `$list` is a regular array, meaning that, as [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54375313/1630171) pointed out in his answer, appending to it with the `+=` assignment operator will re-create the array with size increased by 1, put the new item in the new empty slot, then replace the original array. For a small number of append operations this usually isn't a big issue, but with increasing number of append operations the performance impact becomes significant.

Using an `ArrayList` instead of a plain array avoids this issue:

```
$list = New-Object Collections.ArrayList

$tuple1 = New-Object 'Tuple[String,String]' 'dog', 'cat'
$tuple2 = New-Object 'Tuple[String,String]' 'dog', 'horse'

$list.Add($tuple1) | Out-Null
$list

# Output:
#
# Item1 Item2 Length
# ----- ----- ------
# dog   cat        2

$list.Add($tuple2) | Out-Null
$list

# Output:
#
# Item1 Item2 Length
# ----- ----- ------
# dog   cat        2
# dog   horse      2
```

The `Add()` method of `ArrayList` objects outputs the index where the item was appended. `Out-Null` suppresses that output that is in most cases undesired. If you want to work with these index numbers you can collect them in a variable instead of discarding them (`$i = $list.Add($t1)`).

If you want to avoid having to specify the type of a new tuple all the time you can wrap it into a reusable function like this:

```
function New-Tuple {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateCount(2,2)]
        [string[]]$Values
    )

    New-Object 'Tuple[String,String]' $Values
}

$tuple1 = New-Tuple 'dog', 'cat'
$tuple2 = New-Tuple 'dog', 'horse'
```

or, in a more generic way, like this:

```
function New-Tuple {
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]
        [ValidateCount(2,20)]
        [array]$Values
    )

    Process {
        $types = ($Values | ForEach-Object { $_.GetType().Name }) -join ','
        New-Object "Tuple[$types]" $Values
    }
}

$tuples = ('dog', 'cat'), ('dog', 'horse') | New-Tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mklement0 as below is probably the simplest solution

```
$b = , @{ dog = "cat"} 
$b += @{ dog = "horse"}
```

And Persistent13's method also yields an easy route

```
$ht = @{foo='bar'}
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]]::new()
$list.Add($ht)
$list.Add($ht)
$list.Add($ht)
$list
```

I suppose i was just surprised that there wasn't a more ingrained way to get what i feel is a pretty basic/standard object type